# Is it possible to play audio to a line after making a call with Inbound socket mode?

Tags: ruby, telephony, freeswitch

I'm working on a CRON or some other external event triggered action which is supposed to make a call and play a sound file using FreeSwitch. I suppose I have to use Inbound event socket mode for that.

When using Outbound mode (triggerd by incoming calls), I can play a file since all [DialPlanTools](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Category%3aDptools) are available. For Inbound mode, only a limited number of commands called, [mod_socket](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_commands) is available, and `playback` is not one of them . I also intend to use `say`, `record`, `read` and maybe others.

I use Outbound socket mode in a separate server to handle the incoming calls, and it doesn't seem to be an easy task to pass the context over. I cannot use Outbound socket, as it is not persistent and FreeSwitch immediately drops connection once the call is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freeswitch is tricky. [Stanislav Sinyagin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461066/stanislav-sinyagin) has advised `uuid_broadcast`, but it didn't work alone. You need to add another command (`uuid_phone_event`) immediately for it to work. The overall code is as follows:

```
originate sofia/external/sip:+<phone_number_here>@<freeswitch_ip_here> &park
# wait for remote side to pick up the call
uuid_broadcast <uuid_from_originate> speak::cepstral|david|'Some text in single quotes here' aleg
uuid_phone_event <uuid_from_originate>

uuid_broadcast <uuid_from_originate> playback::'<absolute_path_to_mp3_or_wav>' aleg
uuid_phone_event <uuid_from_originate>

sched_hangup +1 <uuid_from_originate>
```

There a bit less than none documentation on the `uuid_phone_event` command in FS wiki, and I have accidently spotted it in `fs_cli`.
And yes, you need another Inbound socket connection to monitor the events (at least no Ruby library supports for listening for server-generated events and issuing commands on the same socket connection).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed the "full" parameter: 
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_socket_outbound

Comment: I guess you missed that I'm using Inbound event socket.
Using `full` in Outbound mode requires implementation of application-level event dispatcher, and this is not what i would like to focus on.

Comment: yes, right, overlooked that. Still I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. You can easily find me in Skype, will be great to talk.

Comment: Will add more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

uuid_displace call_uuid start /path/to/file